# Error al parsear JSON

Tags: android, json

Tengo un problema al parsear un JSON, reutilizando código fuente que tenía:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String...args) {
    String datos = leeJSon(this.ruta);
    Log.d("1", datos);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(datos);
        String strData = jsonObject.getString(""); //Puede que haya que quitar esta línea
        JSONArray jsonContent = new JSONArray(strData);
        int numItems = jsonContent.length();
        MainActivity.hacks = new Hack[numItems];
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            JSONObject itemJson = jsonContent.getJSONObject(i);
            Hack hack = new Hack();
            hack.setTitle(itemJson.getString("Title"));
            hack.setBreachDate(itemJson.getString("BreachDate"));
            hack.setDescription(itemJson.getString("Description"));
            MainActivity.hacks[i] = hack;
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

private String leeJSon(String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

        }
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Seria de agrado que si puedes especificar los deprecates cuales son

Comment: @Webserveis Son HttpClient, DefaultHttpClien, httpGet y ClientProtocolException. Pero mi mayor problema ahora es hacer que funcione y poder recorer el JSON que es lo que me está fallando al llegar a   String strData = jsonObject.getString("")

Comment: Esta linea es incorrecta  String strData = jsonObject.getString(""); tal vez necesitas definir un valor, te sugiero agregues el archivo json de respuesta con eso podemos definir que valor necesitas ahí.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient`, `DefaultHttpClient`, `httpGet` y `ClientProtocolException` son clases de [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), tienes que cambiar tu implementación usando **[HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**

si es necesario usar las clases de Apache temporalmente, tienes que agregar dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

lo recomendable es cambiar a **[HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**

En cuanto a que en esta línea tienes un problema :

```
 String strData = jsonObject.getString("");
```

es incorrecto que tenga un string vacio, tienes que definir que valor obtener del json.

o elimina esa línea y  define cual es el nombre del array:

```
// String strData = jsonObject.getString(""); 
  JSONArray jsonContent = new JSONArray("nombre del array");
```